# Push Notification Alert

Tags: mql4, indicator, forex, mt4

I have indicator mt4 that has not push notification alert and phone alert. I have no coding knowledge and need your support to add notification alert on this indicator when arrow appears. It doesn't matter if arrow disappears. I just need when first arrow appears, alert must pop up.

If someone helps me, I will add here its coding.

Thanks

Indicator needs to add push notification alert for both computer and phone.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.